# imageview set selector file use programmatically no effect. (Android)

Tags: android, imageview, selector

I want to use code generate imageview and use my selector file.

My selector file (`xxx_selector.xml`) is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/xxx_off" android:state_pressed="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/xxx_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/xxx_off"/>

</selector>
```

My code is below:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

ImageView img = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
img.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx_selector ));
contentLayout.addView( img, layout);
```

But when I click the image, it has no effect.

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageViews` are normally not clickable so probably the "click" state is not firing.

Try adding

```
img.setClickable(true);
img.setEnabled(true);
```